# Is there such a thing as labeled or unlabeled break in C?

Tags: c, switch-statement, break, labeled-statements

As is the case in Java where the `break` statement can be labeled or unlabeled, is there a statement in C which is either the equivalent or achieves the same process?

Comment: But there is `goto`, which Java doesn't have.

Comment: you can think of the `break` statement as unlabeled break and `goto` as an extended labeled brake.

Comment: @Antony Nepgen  The labeled break statement in Java is a demonstration of a bad style of programming by the authors of the language and nothing more.

Comment: The best way to do such things in C and Java both, is to wrap the whole switch inside a function and use a `return`. That's the "least spaghetti" way.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, there are no labeled break-statements like in Java. 
You can, however, use the `goto`-statement to achieve a similar effect. Just declare a label right after the loop you actually want to exit, and use a `goto` where you would have used a labeled break in Java:

```
int main() {

    for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
        switch(i) {
            case 0: printf("just started\n"); break;
            case 10: printf("reached 10\n"); break;
            case 20: printf("reached 20; exiting loop.\n"); goto afterForLoop;
            case 30: printf("Will never be reached."); break;
        }
    }
afterForLoop:

    printf("first statement after for-loop.");

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
just started
reached 10
reached 20; exiting loop.
first statement after for-loop.
```

Note that since Dijkstras famous paper [Go To Statement Considered Harmful](http://homepages.cwi.nl/~storm/teaching/reader/Dijkstra68.pdf) computer scientists have fought hard for banning `goto`-statements from code, because this statement often introduces much more complexity than control structures like `if` or `while`. So be aware what you do and use it wisely (= rarely).

Comment: Funny how this example of goto is actually much clearer than Java-spaghetti programming with labelled break/continue. They refused to implement goto in the language, then come up with something else ten times worse than goto...

Comment: @Lundin You have a similar phenomenon with Golang's defer keyword. A `goto cleanup` is more intuitive, but not supported by the language.

Comment: @Lundin I disagree with this being clearer. I would find `break LOOP_NAME;` equally clear, but perhaps a slight bit easier to read, because I would read the loop name when reading the loop header and associate the label with the loop itself onward.